# Control the number of intermediate points between two vertices - Extension of Bresenham's algorithm

Tags: c++, geometry, bresenham

I have the following working Bresenham's algorithm,which finds intermediate points between two vertices.But this is for a pixel of size 1.

```
void Bresenham(int x1,
    int y1,
    int const x2,
    int const y2)
{
    int delta_x(x2 - x1);
    // if x1 == x2, then it does not matter what we set here
    signed char const ix((delta_x > 0) - (delta_x < 0));
    delta_x = std::abs(delta_x) << 1;

    int delta_y(y2 - y1);
    // if y1 == y2, then it does not matter what we set here
    signed char const iy((delta_y > 0) - (delta_y < 0));
    delta_y = std::abs(delta_y) << 1;

    cout << "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ")\n";
    //plot(x1, y1);

    if (delta_x >= delta_y)
    {
        // error may go below zero
        int error(delta_y - (delta_x >> 1));

        while (x1 != x2)
        {
            // reduce error, while taking into account the corner case of error == 0
            if ((error > 0) || (!error && (ix > 0)))
            {
                error -= delta_x;
                y1 += iy;
            }
            // else do nothing

            error += delta_y;
            x1 += ix;

            cout << "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ")\n";
            //plot(x1, y1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // error may go below zero
        int error(delta_x - (delta_y >> 1));

        while (y1 != y2)
        {
            // reduce error, while taking into account the corner case of error == 0
            if ((error > 0) || (!error && (iy > 0)))
            {
                error -= delta_y;
                x1 += ix;
            }
            // else do nothing

            error += delta_x;
            y1 += iy;

            cout << "(" << x1 << "," << y1 << ")\n";
            //plot(x1, y1);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to control the number of intermediate points formed between the two given vertices.In the code above,I am not able to control it currently.

For e.g: If I have vertices (0,0) and (3,3); if I want 2 points in between,it would be (1,1) and (2,2).

Could you please suggest the changes to be done in my code so that I can control the number of intermediate points between given two vertices and also ,please let me know the way to determine the length of each pixel(as currently,the pixel size is fixed to be 1)

I want my overall function to look like : void Bresenham(int x1,
    int y1,
    int const x2,
    int const y2, int TotalIntermediatePoints)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't need Bresenham algo at all.
And intermediate points might have non-integer coordinates.

Just use linear interpolation

```
 x[i] = x0 + (x1-x0) * i / (N + 1)
```

Comment: Do you think,I can implement 2D Linear Interpolation.If you dont mind,could you please share the algo,so that I can try it out and find it.Also,please explain how do I determine the size of the pixel,which has the intermediate point as its center.

Comment: I've already written formula (similar for Y). Piece size is length(segment) divided by N

Comment: The 'N' in your code is Number of Intermediate points (or) Number of Divisions ?? So,if the vertices are (0,0) and (5,0); intermediate points are 5, Pixel size would be 5/5 = 1? Is that right?

Comment: But if I have three Edges of a triangle, then if distance between vertex1 and vertex2(connecting edge1); vertex2 and vertex 3(connecting edge2) is different, then even the length of Pieces(or pixels like square) drawn between along edge 1 and edge 2 is different right? if thats the case,how would I apply filling algorithm? Plz explain.

Comment: But if I have three Edges of a triangle, then if distance between vertex1 and vertex2(connecting edge1); vertex2 and vertex 3(connecting edge2) is different, then even the length of Pieces(or pixels like square) drawn between along edge 1 and edge 2 is different right? if thats the case,how would I apply filling algorithm? Plz explain.

Comment: What is your **real** problem?

Comment: He wants to rasterize a triangle and write a MMORPG.